# NodeJS Mongoose Stream is inaccurate, gives far more results than actually exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of 1011 strings.

I'm trying to create a stream in Mongoose.

Like so:

```
    var cursor = Domain.find({
        domain: {
            $in: list
        }
    }).stream();
```

Nothing fancy. I can verify that the list size is 1011 results. I can also go into `mongoDB shell` and do `db.domains.find({domain:{$in: [paste in the big list here]}}).count();` and I get `1011`.

However, in the stream I'm getting hundreds more results than (a) I should be getting, and (b) exist in my database.

A simple test I've set up is as follows:

```
    var tempo = 0;
    var cursor = Domain.find({
        domain: {
            $in: list
        }
    }).stream();

    cursor.on('data', function(rec) {
        tempo++;
        console.log(tempo);
    });
```

If I run this I get 1529 results logged in my terminal.

Very confusing. What's going on here?

Comment: Can I suggest a further test here. Since `list` is an array then perhaps do `if ( list.indexOf(rec.domain) != -1) { tempo++; } else { miscount++; }` which would prove that you really are getting results that were not specified in your `$in` condition. But I doubt this will be the case, as I think this is just a pure misconception of what you "think" you are submitting in a test query to what is actually being submitted when your live code runs. It's just not possible for an `$in` condition to find things that are not specified within that list. So other code not listed is the fault here.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Well I'm console logging `list` before the cursor starts, then putting it into MongoDB Shell and returning a count. The count says 1011. What appears to be happening is that some records are being pulled out more than once...

Comment: Use the code I told you to. That would provide the only proof that what you say is true. It is just not possible that you are running the same thing in your code as in the shell and returning a different count of results. I see no reason why domain should be unique and is therefore perfectly valid to match multiple times. The only way you get different results is because you are doing different things.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Well the code you suggested is testing whether the domain name is in the list - I'm not contesting that, I'm saying that the stream is pulling out duplicates. In the live code there is lots of pausing and resuming of the cursor, might that produce a buggy stream with duplicate results?

Comment: Lets be clear here. You have not dicovered a bug in a driver. The only thing buggy here is your own code. If you think you are getting erroneous results then the burden of proof is on you. If you can show something here that is a reproducible case that others can also use to show that returned results are different in two cases then people will ( I will ) look into it. Until then you need to look closely at what your code is actually doing as you are certainly not doing the same things. In fact my number 1 bet is that you actually have two collections.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that I've found a bug, I'm saying buggy results as in my code is producing something unintentional. I've just added in a check for `if(cursor.paused){cursor.resume()}` in my resuming operation and that seems to have fixed the issue - it seems that calling `resume()` when the stream is not paused causes duplicates. Definitely only one collection and definitely only 1011 documents in it.